# ¿Como setear Gridview con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Tengo este código donde devuelvo un DataTable en un JSON y necesitó establecer sus datos en un GrdView.

Código C#:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public  JsonResult ProcesosContables()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string pathArchivo = string.Empty;
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["PathArchivo"] == null)
                return Json(dt);
            else
                pathArchivo = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["PathArchivo"].ToString();

            dt = FuncionGame.ProcesosContables();
            return Json(dt);
        }
```

Código JavaScript:

```
function ProcesosContables() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Process/ProcesosContables",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
           **AQUI EL CODIGO QUE NESECITO**
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: porque en un GridView? los controles de servidor de asp.net no se llevan con codigo del lado del cliente, no puede definir simplemente una tabla html y crear en esta las rows en base al json

Comment: Y si devuelves un StringBuilder con el html del Gridview dibujado con el dt?, en el JavaScript solo pondrías: <control>.append(data);

Answer (score 0):

Usar javascript o jquery para cargar un grid no es buena idea. Ademas de su integracion con el viewstate no lo hace apto para lo que planteas

deberías usar  jqgrid

[jqGrid](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2011/11/jqgrid-listar-orden-compra-maestro.html)

este si esta pensado para ser 100% compatible con jquery y javascript, el gridview no lo es.